# CSS to SWF using mxmlc

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript, flex4, adobe

I want to convert css file into swf for performance related issues.
I am running below command.

C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4 Plug-in\sdks\4.1.0\bin>
mxmlc -el=D:\eclipse\Branch_3.0.0.1\colt-framework\colt-lib-flex\src\main\resources\assets\morcomImages\  D:\eclipse\Branch_3.0.0.1\colt-framework\colt-lib-flex\src\main\resources\assets\morcomJPMSTD.css

but getting error as cannot resolve imports in morcomJPMSTD.css though I have given path to the directory

Can someone help?

Comment: Lots of things I don't understand here.  What is in the css file? How would converting a CSS file to a SWF improve performance?  What peformance problems are you having?  What is the 'colt-framework' I see in your directory structure?  What imports did you put in the CSS file?

Comment: 1.I came to know somewhere that instead of linking css file to your swf at the compile time, if you link the CSS at runtime using the "CSS converted to SWF", it improves your swf load time little bit.2. CSS file includes the styles and some imports of images in other directory under project directory.3.SWF load time is very high.4.Colt-framework is swc refererrd by another few projects.

Comment: 5.imports are like this------mx|MenuBar
{
 background-skin: Embed(source="assets/morcomImages/menuBg.png"); 
 background-size: "100%";
 menuStyleName: menuStyleName;
 selectionColor:#ccc8be;
 color: #321b0f;
 itemOverSkin: Embed(source="assets/morcomImages/menuDown.png");
 itemDownSkin: Embed(source="assets/morcomImages/menuDown.png");
}